# Different JS Syntax - How to add these properties to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, quill

I have two js codes which are similar to each other.

The question is more related to js than the library.
I'm using quilljs library to implement a text editor, and i can customize it's settings before loading the library.

I already configured the library that way :

```
var toolbarOptions = [
  [{ 'font': [] }],
  [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
  [{ 'align': [] }],
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
  [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
  ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

  [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
  [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
  [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
  [ 'link', 'video', 'formula' ], 
  ['clean']                                        // remove formatting button
];

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose a post...',
  theme: 'snow',
  'image-tooltip': true,
  'link-tooltip': true
});

$('#contenthidden').val(quill.root.innerHTML);

     );
```

Anyway, I need to add the code below into toolbarOptions variable obviously, then i have to load the quilljs etc. etc...
 but its content is completely different. Javascript wise i couldn't understand how to add this toolbarOptions variable's content to first one above.

```
var toolbarOptions = {
  handlers: {
    // handlers object will be merged with default handlers object
    'link': function(value) {
      if (value) {
        var href = prompt('Enter the URL');
        this.quill.format('link', href);
      } else {
        this.quill.format('link', false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like omitting:

```
toolbar : { container : containerOptions, handlers : handlerOptions }
```

and doing just:

```
toolbar : containerOptions
```

is just a shortcut since the `container` option is so common. So you'll have to use the first form to specify the handler options.

```
var toolbarOptions = {
    container: [
      [{ 'font': [] }],
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
      [{ 'align': [] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
      [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
      ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
      [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
      [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
      [ 'link', 'video', 'formula' ], 
      ['clean']                                        // remove formatting button
    ],
  handlers: {
    // handlers object will be merged with default handlers object
    'link': function(value) {
      if (value) {
        var href = prompt('Enter the URL');
        this.quill.format('link', href);
      } else {
        this.quill.format('link', false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```